# Unable to concatenate 2 lists using Python (Int and text lists) and to split output data into separate files

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, concatenation

I am facing issue with concatenating data of 2 lists. I have page number (integer value) and table data (text value) both within a list while merging them to print output I am getting this error:

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

My goal is to print following output and also need help to save data from table 3 based on "Aircraft operator ID" keyword into table name "Table 3 A" and data with Header value of "Installation ID" into table name "Table 3 I" into 2 separate tabs of excel file. My code is given below:

```
import time
import requests
import random
from lxml import html  # used to use Xpath
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter

def append_row(ws, row):
    for col, value in enumerate(row):
        ws.write_string(ws.cur_row, col, value)
    ws.cur_row += 1

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Output.xlsx')
ws_3_A = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 3 A")
ws_3_I = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 3 I")

# Keep a track of the row to use in each worksheet
ws_3_A.cur_row = 0  
ws_3_I.cur_row = 0   

# Code starts from here:
start = 1 
end = 3 
link = "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber={}&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods="

for page_number in range(start, end):
    print("Page {}".format(page_number))
    url = link.format(page_number)
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(url)

    serial_no = [int(x) for x in str(page_number)]
    print(serial_no)

    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    # Table 3 Aircraft Operator ID data:
    for items in soup.find(id="tblChildDetails").find("table").find_all("tr")[1:]:
        dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")[:]]
        print(dataset)
        append_row(ws_3_A, serial_no + [url] + dataset)

    # Table 3 Installation ID data:
    for items in soup.find(id="tblChildDetails").find("table").find_all("tr")[1:]:
        dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")[:]]
        print(dataset)
        append_row(ws_3_I, serial_no + [url] + dataset)
workbook.close()
```

Current and Expected output is attached as screenshot. Expected output:
[image]

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\QRS\Script.py", line 42, in <module>
    append_row(ws_3_A, serial_no + [url] + dataset)
  File "D:\QRS\Script.py", line 10, in append_row
    ws.write_string(ws.cur_row, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\varun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 67, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\varun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 500, in write_string
    return self._write_string(row, col, string, cell_format)
  File "C:\Users\varun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 512, in _write_string
    if len(string) > self.xls_strmax:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Error suggests you are using an int instead of a list. Show us the full traceback and related code. If you could remove unrelated parts from your code it would be better.

Comment: Hi Arman, I have updated with trace back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element in `[int(x) for x in str(page_number)]` should be string. Because each element will pass to variable `value` in function `append_row()`.

And then , you want to have an expected output , you need to ignore the first `tr` when `page_number` bigger `start`.

> Use `try...finally` , so you can close workbook when script occured error

```
import time
import requests
import random
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter

def append_row(ws, row):
    for col, value in enumerate(row):
        ws.write_string(ws.cur_row, col, value)
    ws.cur_row += 1

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Output.xlsx')


def ws_3(name):
    return workbook.add_worksheet("Table 3 {}".format(name))


# Code starts from here:
start = 1 
end = 5
link = "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber={}&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods="
coldict = {}
try:
    for page_number in [1,2,3,342,343]:
        print("Page {}".format(page_number))
        url = link.format(page_number)
        r = requests.get(url)

        serial_no = [str(page_number)]

        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

        # Table 3 Aircraft Operator ID data:
        tr = soup.find(id="tblChildDetails").find("table").find_all("tr")
        dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in tr[1].find_all("td")]

        #select or create new table
        if not coldict.get(dataset[0]):
            ws = ws_3(dataset[0])
            ws.cur_row = 0
            coldict[dataset[0]] = ws
            append_row(ws, ["Page no","Url"] + dataset)
        else:
            ws = coldict.get(dataset[0])

        for items in tr[2:]:
            dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")]
            print(url)
            print(dataset)
            append_row(ws, serial_no + [url] + dataset)

finally:
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @kcorlidy, issue got rectified. I posted another query for splitting data of table values based on Header name as "Aircraft Operator ID" and "Installation ID" into separate Excel tabs. Would appreciate if can help on this.

Comment: @Varun i did not find the data name `Installation ID` in the url.

Comment: It's available as a value within table <tr> tag. On the webpage it's shown as title of the headers under "General Information" table. Based on the first title name as "Aircraft operator ID" I want to write data into excel tab "Table 3 A" else it should write data into excel tab "Table 3 I"

Comment: @Varun this is what i understood , it looks just doing something with a bit difference

Comment: Thats ok, but my question is regarding table column name values (header) as "Installation ID" as for majority pages like page no. "342" (as example) it have General information table Column names as "Installation ID" (Under Installation Information) and I want data with header to be written in separate Excel tab in "Table 3 I".

Comment: page 342 : http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&backList=%3C%C2%A0Back&resultList.currentPageNumber=343&selectedPeriods=

Comment: @Varun may be it is what you want , but i change the table name to the first column name of table such as `Table 3 Aircraft Operator ID` , `Table 3 Installation ID`. I think it will be more flexible.

Comment: Yes its giving desired output. Thanks @kcorlidy for helping. Really appreciate your code review